# Python based publish subscribe middleware

Tags: python, middleware, publish-subscribe

Is there a scalable, python based publish subscribe middleware available? I tried RabbitMQ, but it does not scale well over 32-64 nodes.

I need a middleware that could run over >1000 nodes

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what do you mean about 'scalability'. RabbitMQ is designed for high stability with scalability.

There is also [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), designed for very high performance (but less features).
You can see [the performance tests](http://www.zeromq.org/area%3aresults) of ZeroMQ.

Comment: Which leads onto the [RabbitMQ/0MQ bridge](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/10/18/rabbitmq0mq-bridge/) to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Sorry I used 'scalable' loosely

What I want to do is deploy a number of publishers and subscribers on a sample network topology and see how its performance (delays, losses etc.) scales as I increase the number of pubs and subs.